# How would I detect user status? || Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I'm trying to make a bot that when a command is entered. It detects a users online status. I haven't started coding it yet because I really don't know how I would go about it. Would anyone mind helping me?

For a bit more documentation. I want the command to do the following;

1. Take in the command "status"
2. Check the mentioned users status
3. Say what the users status is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for any future viewers this code is outdated, here's my updated version of course you can edit this to your desire

```
@client.command()
async def status(ctx, member : discord.Member=None):
  if member is None:
    member = ctx.author
  embed=discord.Embed(title=f"{member.name} your current status is", description= f'{member.activities[0].name}', color=0xcd32a7)
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`Member.status`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.status) attribute of `Member` objects.  It will be either a value of the [`discord.Status`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Status) enumerated type, or a string.

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord import Member

bot = Bot('!')

@bot.command(pass_context=True, name='status')
async def status(ctx, member: Member):
    await bot.say(str(member.status))

bot.run('token')
```

Comment: Would I turn this into an if statement by just adding; if member.status == 'Online'?

Comment: `if member.status == discord.Status.online:`   Remember to `import discord`