# How to get Discord Member Online Status in Python without bot?

Tags: python, discord, member, status

So I want to print my friend's online status in python but without bot, the code looks like this:

```
from discord import (what should I import?)
from time import sleep

isFriendOnline = "False"
while True:
    sleep(1)
    new_isFriendOnline = (<discord get member online status placeholder>)
    if isFriendOnline != new_isFriendOnline and new_isFriendOnline == False:
        print("Friend is offline now")
    elif isFriendOnline != new_isFriendOnline and new_isFriendOnline == True:
        print("Friend is online now")
    elif isFriendOnline == new_isFriendOnline:
        pass
```

So what do I have to write instead of ?

Answer (score 1):

As you noted in your question, you wanted to do it without using a bot.
For self-botting, you might want to install and use the `discord.py-self` library:

```
$ pip3 install discord.py-self
```

Do note, though, that both the normal `discord.py` and `discord.py-self` use `discord` as an import name, so you will lose the old `discord.py` library if you install it.

Sadly, there is no `discord.User.status`, but there is `discord.Member.status`, so we can use it if you have a mutual server with your friend:

```py
import discord, sys

class FriendWatcherClient(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self, friend, *args, **kwargs):
        self.friend = friend      # Make the friend variable accessible
                                  # to other functions (self.friend)
        
        self.friend_status = None # Will later become a discord.Status
                                  # and be used to keep track of friend's
                                  # status
        self.status_to_str = {discord.Status.online: 'available',
                              discord.Status.dnd: 'busy',
                              discord.Status.idle: 'away',
                              discord.Status.offline: 'offline'
                             }
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    async def on_ready(self):
        # We are now logged in.
        print(f"Logged on as {self.user}")
        
        # We should now search to see if we have the specified friend in
        # our friends list
        friends_list = self.user.friends
        for friend in friends_list:
            if str(friend) == self.friend: # If the friend username matches
                print("Found friend in friend list!")
                if friend.mutual_guilds != []:
                    print("Friend has a mutual guild!")
                else:
                    print("Friend does not have a mutual guild. Sorry.")
                    sys.exit(1) # Exit with an error status
            else:
                print("User was not found in friends list. Sorry.")
                sys.exit(1) # Exit with an error status
    async def on_member_update(self, before, after):
        if str(before) == self.friend:
            if after.status != before.status:
                # User changed their status
                print(f"{str(after)} changed their status to {self.status_to_str[after.status]}")
            if str(before) != str(after):
                # User changed their nickname
                self.friend = str(after)

client = FriendWatcherClient("Username#1234")
token = input("Enter your Discord token: ")
client.run(token)
```

Note: `str(discord.User)` is the same as `f"{discord.User.name}#{discord.User.discriminator}"`. Same goes for `str(discord.Member)`

Answer (score -1):

Found identical question, please do more research next time.

[How would I detect user status? || Discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53807024/12973333)

Comment: Is it possible without discord bot?

Comment: No, you have to use the discord not API. Not sure if this will work if the member is not In the same server as the member either.

Comment: That's not an "identical question". That's just a similar one.